# Flutter Hive unable to retrieve Map{}

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I'm trying to store a Map<String, int>() in the hive database. I'm able to store but I'm not able to retrieve the Map() it prompts the error

```
Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, int>?' in type cast
```

Code:

Data Controller

```
Box<Map<String, int>> hiveBox = Hive.box('SaveBetBox');

  void betStorage({String? matchKey, String? statKey, int? statIndex}) {
    // Checks if the hive box has the data with following key if not adds
    hiveBox.containsKey(matchKey)
        ? null
        : hiveBox.put(
            matchKey,
            Map<String, int>(),
          );
    // Extract hive map to update or add Key values to Map with specific Key
    Map<String, int>? tm = hiveBox.get(matchKey);
    if (tm![statKey!] == null) {
      tm[statKey] = statIndex!;
      hiveBox.put(matchKey, tm);
    } else {
      tm.update(statKey, (value) => statIndex!);
    }
    Map<String, int>? dd = hiveBox.get(matchKey);
    print('This is $statKey ${dd![statKey]}');

  }

// Retrieve FN 
  void onitintHive() {
    //Storing value i.e Map() of specific key  in var
    Map<String, int>? _dd = hiveBox.get("RVB");

    // Extracting values from the map
    int? goal1 = _dd!['t1goalkey'];
    int? yc = _dd['t1yckey'];

    print('This is dd : ${_dd!['t1goalkey']}');
    print('This is T1 Goal : $goal1');
    print('This is T1 YC : $yc');
  }
```

Main Box in main()

```
  await Hive.openBox<Map<String, int>>('SaveBetBox');
```

Comment: edit Box<Map<String, int>> hiveBox = Hive.box('SaveBetBox'); to `Box<Map<String, int>> hiveBox = Hive.box<Map<String, int>> ('SaveBetBox');`

Comment: It's not solving the problem. Still the same error. @CyrustheGreat

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved the problem. I might be wrong but seems like Hive Box return only maps with dynamic types, i.e `Map<dynamic, dynamic>()`. The error occurred because I was trying to fit `Map<dynamic, dynamic>()` to a `Map<String, int>()`. Changing the receiver Map to `Map<dynamic, dynamic>()` solved the issue.

Comment: To expand on this, adding strict types to the map returned from the box looks like this `stuff = boxOfStuff.get('stuff', defaultValue: <String, int>{})!.cast<String, int>();`